# Manipulating each value in a 2D array

Tags: c#, performance

This code is about manipulating each value in a 2D array. My method below is called based on how I want the values in the array to be manipulated (process).

For the first method in the switch statement - as an example, I am calling `AllCaps()` method to manipulate the value.

What I am trying to avoid is repeating statements when I can put it in a method instead and just call it when needed. With my code below, though, it seems like I am making the program work too hard by performing a check on each iteration - which could be in the thousands.

Is it effective to call a method for processing each 2D array value inside the nested for loop? Or call the method first and perform the nested for loop inside each method?

```
private void ProcessSelectedRange(string process)
{
    selectedRange = GetSelectedRange();

    // initialize and populate 2d array with values from selected range
    curValue = new object[,] { };
    curValue = selectedRange.Value;

    // possibly more statements

    // loop through curValue 2d array
    for (int i = 1; i <= curValue.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= curValue.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            string str = string.Empty;

            // continue if curValue[i, j] is null or empty
            try
            {
                str = curValue[i, j].ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) continue;
            }
            catch { continue; }


            //********************************************************************

            // call method depending on what we want to do with the value
            switch (process)
            {
                case "AllCaps": AllCaps(str); break;
                case "Process2": Process2(str); break;
                case "Process3": Process3(str); break;
                case "Process4": Process4(str); break;
                // possibly more methods
                default: Process5(str); break;
            }

            //********************************************************************
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Exception

Avoid getting them being thrown if possible, as they are costly.

```
if (curValue[i, j] == null)
    continue;

var str = curValue[i, j].ToString();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    continue;
```

### Loop

The condition will be evaluated every cycle. You do not need to `GetLength` on each of the loop. The result can be cached :

```
// could be named rowCount and columnCount; I am not sure which is which
var length0 = curValue.GetLength(0), length1 = curValue.GetLength(1)

// when you have 2 for-loop like that, you don't need to intend all of them
// this is mostly a style choice, but it helps to prevent building a pyramid
for (int i = 1; i <= length0; i++)
for (int j = 1; j <= length1; j++)
{
   // ...
}
```

---

The switch part can be moved out of the loop, as the `process` doesn't change during the loop. This can save us from some string comparisons.

```
Action<string> processString;
switch (process)
{
    case "AllCaps": processString = AllCaps; break;
    case "Process2": processString = Process2; break;
    case "Process3": processString = Process3; break;
    case "Process4": processString = Process4; break;
    // possibly more methods
    default: processString = Process5;
}

for (...)
for (...)
{
    // ...
    processString(str);
}
```

Comment: Caching the lengths may not be necessary. The compiler should inline and cache them for you as it does with `Array.Length`, IIRC.

Comment: Please use bracing and indenting in the for loops. Building a pyramid is prevented by refactoring, not be not indenting

Comment: I like this. Thank you for pointing out the Exception. With Loop, I try not to use a variable if I am only using the value once. I think I remember convincing myself that I may be saving some memory allocation by minimizing the use of variables - for one time use. In this case though I understand your point.
Action<>. Now this is interesting. This may also be the answer to one of the programs I am working on.
This is enlightening. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the check on each iteration is definitely a good idea. My advice: have a separate method for each process. E.G.

```
SelectedRange = GetSelectedRange()

AllCapsRange(SelectedRange)
Process2Range(SelectedRange)
```

then, if you need to select a case, you only need to do it once, and not \$n^2\$ times.

As a general rule, the ONLY things that should go inside an iterative loop are things which could change during the iteration. Anything else should be declared/set beforehand.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your view Zak, and I like your general rule. I'll keep that in mind.